# Same regex, different outputs if you try to use tool to batch rename files using regular expressions

Tags: regex

On notepad++ I use this Regex

Find: `(\d{4})|((\d+))`
Replace: `((\1\2))#`

How it works

input:

```
Tenet 2020
Alpha.1999 
beta (1997)
```

output

```
Tenet (2020)#
Alpha.(1999)#
beta (1997)#
```

But if you try to use some software to rename like [Power Renamer](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/tag/v0.56.2) by Microsoft, or RegexRenamer or [Renamer](https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer) you get this output

```
Tenet ((12))#
Alpha.((12))#
beta (((12))#)
```

How can I solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex dialects vary widely between tools. You will need to develop regular expressions based on the tooling you will be using.

In particular I KNOW that ReNamer uses `$` as its capture group delimiter, so you need to change `((\1\2))#` to `($1$2)#`  to work in ReNamer. It looks like the other tools you mention have similar issues.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but for last string it doesn't work because it return me `beta ((1997)#)` and not `beta (1997)`, 1st and 2nd strings are renamed correctly

Comment: the trailing `)`  is because your search pattern doesn't take into account the existance of parentheses in the input. while you have an extra set of parens in your replace expression, your `(\d{4})` capture group doesn't include the leading or trailing parens, so those will not be replaced. try something like `\(?(\d{4})\)?|((\d+))`. that way if there are existing parens, they are not included in the `#1` capture group, but are part of the match.

Comment: Perfect, now it works, thanks

Comment: glad it worked out for you. I do note that the OR expression for your search pattern `((\d+))` is currently unused in the input you provided. consider removing it, combining it with the first search pattern `\(?(\d{4})\)?` as `\(?(\d+\)?`or adding the optional parens to it as well `\(?(\d+)\)?`.